# How can I disable the Netlify error page and use a custom error page instead with NextJS?

Tags: next.js, netlify

We have a NextJS app hosted on Netlify. We implemented custom error pages using the NextJS _error.js file but when a 404 or 500 error occurs, instead of showing the NextJS error page, we get the Netlify error page.

Is there something in the netlify.toml that we have to disable so that we get our own NextJS error page instead? Or is there another solution

[image: Netlify Error Page][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krA3Q.png)

Answer (score 1):

To use a custom 404 error page, you'll want to use the [custom 404 page](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-error-page#404-page) at `pages/404.js` instead of `pages/_error.js`, since the 404 page will be statically generated. `_error.js` appears to be mainly for 500 or other server errors. See this [tutorial](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2020/12/08/making-a-custom-404-page-in-next.js/) for more information, or the [Next.js docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-error-page).

To use your new static 404 page with Netlify, you can create a [custom 404 redirect](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/redirect-options/#custom-404-page-handling) with Netlify, which will be shown instead of the default 404 page.

To configure a 404 redirect with the [`netlify.toml` syntax](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/#syntax-for-the-netlify-configuration-file):

```toml
[[redirects]]
  from = "/*"
  to = "/404"
  status = 404
```

Comment: So there is no way to show an error page for a 500 error page generated by the _error.js through netlify?

Comment: @pratnayake Sorry, I might have misunderstood your question. Are you getting the Netlify 404 page on 500 errors in your application too? 404 pages are statically generated since they're more common, but 500 error pages are rendered when an error occurs.

Comment: @person_v1.32 He is asking, How do you let Next handle both 404s and 500s, and stop Netlify from responding to them? He has custom logging on his Next _error.js, and it is not getting fired because Netlify is intercepting this. (I know this because I am his colleague)